# Is there a way to create a native view on top of cordova's webview? (prevent pull down menu)

Tags: android, ios, cordova, webview

I would like to create a native view on top of my webview, because the application is meant to be used as a kiosk and I don't want users to pull down the device settings panel.

Creating a webview with the topbar's size will alow me to consume all touch events preventing it from happening.

Does anyone know how I can create an interface/plugin for android and ios to accomplish that?

Comment: What don't you make a fullscreen app instead? (see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html#global-preferences)

Comment: No @fiddler. The fullscreen hides the topbar but still doesn't prevent you from pulling down the menu which gives you access to the device settings such as network and notifications

Comment: I think that somehow violates the OS design guidelines (whatever it is - iOS or Android). Such an app would probably never be granted access to the store.

Comment: As I said it's a kiosk application. It's meant to be used by anyone so it must work like that.

Comment: You should just execute the app in kiosk mode

Comment: @jcesarmobile could you be more precise? I think there are no such thing in android. The most close to that is called androidWidgets introduced in android 4.2

Comment: If you google android kiosk mode you'll find tutorials. It's not really a kiosk mode, but a way of launching the app on startup and keeping the user inside of the app. On android 5 google has implemented ScreenPinning, that works like a kiosk mode https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenPinning